# Overdispersion problem in a quasi-binomial GLM (for proportional data)

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, overdispersion, quasi-likelihood

Below is the summary of a GLM I built for a response variable which is proportional (derived from count data). My only predictor is a continuous one (environmental measurement). And my sample size is really low: only 16.

```r
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(HE, FailureHE) ~ MeanWLScaled, 
    family = quasibinomial, data = FG.WL.Beysehir)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-143.874   -43.207    -3.412    53.815   198.205  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    1.5245     0.3087   4.939 0.000218 ***
MeanWLScaled  -1.5244     0.4273  -3.567 0.003092 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 8875.282)

    Null deviance: 295541  on 15  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 140148  on 14  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

As far as my very limited GLM knowledge goes, there is still overdispersion here. My question is what can I do to deal with overdispersion in this case? My measurements are from different years which are: 1967 1990 1996 1999 2002 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2013 2014 2015 2016. So there aren't predefined "clusters". Should I still use "Year" as an observation level random effect and go with GLMM?

Comment: 16 observations is too few! Try to get more data ... maybe you could try to include year as a covariate, with a spline ...